# Linq - Conditional Where / Find

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following 2 lines,

```
var productStrucutre = _service.GetProductStructureWithParent(partId).ToList(); // returns a list of objects
var product = productStrucutre.Find(_ => _.Part == part); // Returns a part
```

if the following condition fails because the `par`t does not exist, then i would like to return the whole product structure.

```
var product = productStrucutre.Find(_ => _.Part == part);
```

So the `find` will fall away

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, try rephrasing your question a bit. Perhaps add a sample of what you want. As a side-note, don't use `_` as a lambda argument - the semantics of `_` is "I don't care about this value" - if you actually *use it*, you obviously *do* care, and it should have a name.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing to me (maybe to other too). In particular what do you mean by "I want to return the whole object."?

Comment: Let me rephrase quickly, i read it now it yea it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean something like this:

```
var productStructure = _service.GetProductStructureWithParent(partId).ToList();
var product = productStrucutre.Where(x => x.Part == part);

return product.Any() ? 
    product :         // return only those products that fit the condition
    productStructure; // return all objects
```

Comment: If Part is a class, then plan to override Equals method, else == as suggested above will not work. Also you may have to override GetHashCode

Comment: In the second case you can use FirstOrDefault instead of Where and SingleOrDefault.

Comment: The conditional operator can only work if product and productStructure are from the same type. Just saying before anyone struggles with this. :)

Comment: @ar53nic Yeap, you´re right, I´ve deleted that section from my answer.